# Can I get a list of Sways through Microsoft Graph

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api

I'd like to access a user's list of sways via the Microsoft Graph APIs however I can't see a way to do it in the docs ( http://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs )

The use case is that we are an ISV and we've implemented Office365 / AzureAD SSO and are now looking at presenting the user with a way to navigate their OneDrive so they can select a file to be linked in our app (this looks straightforward).

I'd also like to allow the user to to perform the same workflow with sways - so see a list of their sways along with the keyframe. The user would then select the sway and we would embed it in our app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not yet, but this is something we want too and we're working on.  We don't have any ETA statement to make as of May 2016.